# Chrome css transition: text with filter disappears

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Chrome hides text with filter while transition is running. I have the following code:

```css
.c1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.c1 h1 {
  transition: transform ease 0.5s;
  margin: 0;
}

.c1 h1:hover {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

.c2 {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <h1>a long long title header, very long</h1>
</div>

<div class="c2">
  some text
</div>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzXMQp

When you're mouseover the h1, "some text" disappears. After transition ends, the text is visible again. It reproduces only in Chrome (67), in Firefox is ok (haven't tried any other tho). What is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Change your h1 styles like this


.c1 h1 {
    transition: transform ease 0.5s;
    margin: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}    and check if it fixes it ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma it didn't help. You can try it yourself in codepen before post an answer, can't you

Comment: Did i post an answer ?!! i just asked you to try something in the comment. Its was not replicable on my chrome so i was just wild guessing something that might fix it !

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma thank you for trying, I didn't know it wasn't replicable. Anybody can reproduce it at all? Maybe it's only my local problem

Comment: I added your code snippet here itself. May be someone can help you out.